# CSS-Transform with dynamic max-height doesn't work on Chrome for IOS (in a ReactJS project)

Tags: ios, reactjs, google-chrome, css-transforms

Consider a React component.

There is a DIV with the following CSS style:

```
.bracketRow
  display: flex
  flex-direction: row
  -webkit-transition: all 1s
  -moz-transition: all 1s
  -ms-transition: all 1s
  -o-transition: all 1s
  transition: all 1s
  max-height: 400px
```

The DIV looks like this:

```
<div className="bracketRow" style={{ maxHeight: `${getBracketRowHeight()}px`}}>
```

As you can see, the max-height is dynamic and it changes.
This works wonderfull in any desktop browser. In IOS it works in Safari but it doesn't in Chrome.
In Chrome for IOS (IOS 13, Chrome 80), there is no animation, the max-height directly goes from one value to the new one.

They key here is the inline style function, if I change the max-height elsewhere, the animation works fine in Chrome for IOS. It doesn't work only if I get the max-height value from the function dynamically.

Thank you very much community.

Answer (score 0):

Mistery solved.

The CSS works. The reason is the function has a state in the paramenters. 
That state changes more than it should because of the scrolling on IOS. 
Only in IOS, when a div changes its max-height, the scrolling speeds up, so it behaves wierd and hard to predict.